# Store images in iOS app directory when install

Tags: ios

I am writing an iOS app which download images from a backend server, and store them in the document directory. I know how it is done.

But I need to write a prototype first, which use some pre-given images (not retrieve from the backend server). My question is, is it possible to store images in the document directory during initial installation of the app? I don't want to hardcode them in the bundle directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing can be done when the app is installed, only when the app is run. The first time the app runs, you can either copy pre-bundled images to the other directory (Documents) or you can download them as needed. It sounds like you want the first option for the prototype.

Basically you need to do what you don't want to do - hardcode them in the bundle.

Remember, the app's sandbox is setup when the app is installed. This includes the creation of the Documents directory. But nothing is put there. Only your running app can store something somewhere in the app's sandbox.